# What is the data type for JSON?

Tags: php, json, document, dataformat

I am writing a php method according to phpDocumentor format. The method just returns json, and I wrote String at the momemnt. I am wondering is this correct?

```
/**
 * This is a method returns json
 * @return String
 */
public function _getJsonData() {
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ... but no.

You are right that a function returning JSON is returning a string as far as PHP's type system is concerned, and that's all phpDocumentor cares about.

However, by convention the built-in type is always lower-case, and a leading upper-case letter would indicate a class name, so you should be using `@return string` not `@return String`.

Note also that unless you need your code to run on really old versions of PHP, you can specify the return type in the function signature itself:

```php
public function _getJsonData(): string {
  .....
}
```

At that point, just specifying `@return string` is fairly pointless, but adding a *description* of the string might be more useful:

```php
/**
 * @return string A string formatted in JSON ready for use with the frobulator
 */
public function _getJsonData(): string {
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a JSON response is a string.

Of course, this says nothing about what "meaning" this string-value actually conveys.